# How could I use two (wifi and lan) mac address for single ip in dhcp?

Tags: dhcp

In my office we using both WiFi and LAN if I am set IPv4 automatic it is coming a different ip are coming.

In my server I able give single MAC address if I give LAN mac its coming properly for LAN not for WiFi and if I am set WiFi MAC address WiFi working fine not LAN

How could we use a single IP for both MAC address?

[image]

Comment: some operating systems allow you to set same IP for both MACS, and then set interface priority to set which one you want to use. but it is an un supported configuration with unicast mac address.  If you have a multicast mac address, then multiple can listen.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the WiFi MAC to spoof your LAN MAC. This will not allow you to use both interfaces at the same time, but if you only use one at a time, both interfaces should receive the same IP address from your DHCP server.

I am not sure, however, how to do this on Windows.